# Finding a vector space dealing with derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le 3$. Define a subspace
$$W = \{p ∈ V : p'(3) = 0\}.$$

Find a basis for $W$.

I'm unsure of where to even start.

Comment: Write $\;p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\;$, so $\;p'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c\;$ . Now, find restrictions to $\;a,b,c,d\;$ in those polynomials that fulfill $\;p'(3)=0\;$ ...and now do, finally, some mathematics.

Comment: @DonAntonio How do I find the restrictions on a,b,c,d?

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in W \iff$

$$p'(3)=27a+6b+c=0$$

thus

$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+x(-27a-6b)+d$$

$$=a(x^3-27x)+b(x^2-6x)+d$$

so, a basis of $W$ is

$$(x^3-27x, x^2-6x, 1)$$

Comment: How did you jump from ax3+bx2+cx+d to p′(3)=27a+6b+c. I know there must be an intermediate step of finding the derivative, but other than that I don't see how those number came up. They seem arbitrary.

Comment: $p'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c $ and $x=3$

Comment: @frillybob Ok ? you see now.

Comment: Ahh I see now. But I still don't understand the rest. How did you know what to substitute into the rest of the equations?

Comment: $a,b,d$ are the coefficient of linear combination $aU+bV+dW$ .

Comment: Why is c not? Did you row reduce something to find out that c was not a dependent variable (not a pivot column)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47660/discussion-between-frillybob-and-abdallah-hammam).